# NaN result when sum values

Tags: jquery

Have an test script that would like to sum values but get it the result: total:NaN (need to sum all columns except the first column. From 2 and 6 column)
The table containts only number from 2 and 6 column.

The code PHP and script are in the same file and this is my code

Here is the script:

```
<script>
       var totals=[0,0,0,0,0];
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var $dataRows=$("#mytable tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");
            $dataRows.each(function() {
                $(this).find('.rowDataSd').each(function(i){        
                    totals[i]+=parseInt( $(this).html());
                });
            });
            $("#mytable td.totalCol").each(function(i){  
                $(this).html(totals[i]);
            });
        });
</script>
```

And the php have this code:

```
<table id="mytable">
 <thead>
 <tr class="titlerow">
 <th scope="col">Column1</th>
 <th>Column2</th>
 <th>Column3</th>
 <th>Column4</th>
 <th>Column5</th>
 <th>Column6</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <?php
 include("conn.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 GROUP BY name");

 while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 $id = $test['id']; 
 echo"<td>".$test['name']."</td>";
 echo"<td class='rowDataSd'>".$test['value1']."</td>";
 echo"<td class='rowDataSd'>".$test['value2']."</td>";
 echo"<td class='rowDataSd'>".$test['value3']."</td>";
 echo"<td class='rowDataSd'>".$test['value4']."</td>";
 echo"<td class='rowDataSd'>".$test['value5']."</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }
 mysql_close($conn);
 echo '<tfoot>
    <tr class="totalColumn">
        <td>.</td> 
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td> 
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td> 
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td> 
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td> 
        <td class="totalCol">Total:</td> 
    </tr>
</tfoot>';
 ?>
</table>
```

Comment: The NaN is from your JavaScript so the PHP seems irrelevant here. Post the rendered HTML please and remove the PHP tag.

Comment: php contains info about the class object and the construction. yes. it's right that the problem are into jquery.

Comment: Getting `NaN` means that the value you pass to `parseInt` cannot be converted to a "proper" number. Since we don't know what the values are, there is no much else to say.

Comment: Couple of things, you seem to have closing `</a>`s on each cell. but no opening anchor tag. Secondly, you should be calling `parseInt($(this).text())` instead of `.html()`

Comment: @AravindanVe I update and remove the </a>. I tried to simplify code. What should I do and where to modify?

Answer (score 0):

the `parseInt` returns NaN when the value is not correct number, you can clear your data by using this:

```
$(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

Comment: where I put it?

Comment: instead `totals[i]+=parseInt( $(this).html());` use this `totals[i]+=parseInt($(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));`

Comment: same result: "total:NaN"